# Using momentjs how to get today's midday

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to get today's midday.

*Please don't confuse the post with another StackOverflow post which says "How to get last midday in moments" which is unanswered and want to get the last date.*

**I want to get the current date not last**

For example:

**If today is 2020-05-12T22:00:00 should return 2020-05-12T12:00:00 and that's too in the same time zone.**

I'm looking for something preexisting function in the moment if it exists.

Is there any method example: moment().someFunction(12, 'd').

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `moment-timezone` to specify the timezone . Get the `start of the day` and then add `12 hours` to it to give you the desired format

```js
console.log(
   moment("2020-05-12T22:00:00")
    .tz("America/Los_Angeles")
    .startOf("day")
    .hour(12)
    .minute(0)
    .format()
);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Get the start of the current day and add 12 hours in it .**

```
    var  now = moment()
    var startdate =now.startOf('day');
    var midday = startdate.add(moment.duration(12, 'hours'));
    console.log(midday.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the midday in any way you can do it like this. I didn't use moment.js in this example.

```js
function getMidDate(date){
   
    var dateParts = date.toLocaleString().split(":");
    var hour = dateParts[0].replace(dateParts[0].split(" ")[1],"12");
    var min = dateParts[1].replace(dateParts[1],"00")
    var sec = dateParts[2].replace(dateParts[2],"00");
    var middateString = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec + "+0000";
    var midDate = new Date(Date.parse(middateString));
    return midDate;
}
var date = new Date();
console.log(getMidDate(date));
```